# Консоль выдает ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

Идея в том , что бы код считал сколько есть слов в массиве , которые заканчиваются "у"  "іе"

```js
let arr = new Array();
arr = ["Афафy","Азазааз","алфыалфаыл","алфыалфаie","алфыалфаыл"];
function e_names(x) {
  for (i = 0, i < x.length, i++) {
    if ((x[x.length - 1] == "y") || ((x[x.length - 1] == "e")&&(x[x.length - 2] == "i"))  ) {
      summ++;
    }
  }
  alert(summ);
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0, i < x.length, i++)` запятые, а  надо `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = ["Афафy","Азазааз","алфыалфаыл","алфыалфаie","алфыалфаыл"];
function e_names(x) {
  let summ = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if ((x[x.length - 1] == "y") || ((x[x.length - 1] == "e")&&(x[x.length - 2] == "i")) ) {
      summ++;
    }
  }
  console.log(summ);
}

e_names(arr);
```

Comment: А в чем была ошибка?

Comment: @Dyxa Найдите десять отличий :). В запятых в `for(...)`.

Comment: @Dyxa Зачем у Вас вообще цикл, если `i` нигде не используется?

Comment: Они используются , просто конкретно тут я не мог разобраться что не так и стал их добавлять.

Comment: @Dyxa Хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.